# Destination IP-address = '::'

Tags: ip-address

I've got a 'quick and dirty' question:

What does '::' mean in an IP-address field, e.g. Destination-IP, mean?

For example:

| Source-IP | Destination-IP | Username |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10.10.10.10 | :: | abc |

Answer (score 0):

In IPv6 :: is used to compress 16-bit groups of zeroes in order to shorten the representation of the address **so the correspoding ipv4 address to :: is 0.0.0.0**. Check the example image (also added below) to the upper right on this wikipedia article [IPv6 addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address)

[image: IPv6 bit compression]

Comment: [The below quote is from this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0)
"In IPv6, the all-zeros address is typically represented by "::", which is the short notation of 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000.[5] The IPv6 variant serves the same purpose as its IPv4 counterpart."